# Entity Framework 7 scaffolding with original name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need scaffolding my 500+ tables to models and DbContext.
I perform **dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold** command as stated [here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold), but all models created with the name with a capital letter and have been omitted underscores.
How perform scaffold and create models with original names and cases?

Comment: Something changed in a recent-ish release because it used to create them with underscores. It has also changed the case so a table I had called `DR_Orders` where `DR` is an abbreviation is now `DrOrders` (yuk). PS: I see you said EF7 but I think you meant EFCore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a change in the 1.2 release to adjust the powershell parameters according to this :

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6018

They do have a way of specifying it in your own code - where you can write whatever rules you want.

https://gist.github.com/natemcmaster/353f4ab3efb4514eeaec846df28f0e24

Apparently it is not officially supported. Expect more work on this in future.